# How to find which condition is true without using if statement

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

I have two conditions.

What I want to know is which condition is true, both are true/false, or only one is true.

The problem is if I use `if` statements, it increases the amount of code and it doesn't appear like a robust solution.

Are there any conditions or loops in C# which can check and tell in one go?

Can any one provide me with an alternative and clean solution?

Scenario:

```
string  garage = getGarageCost(id)
    string  helmet = getHelmetCost(id)

    if(garage == "")

    {

    string selected =  "dropdown is not selected"
    }

    else if(Convert.ToInt32(garage) >= 1)
    {
    string selected = "dropdown is selected"
    return selected value;
    }

    if(helmet == "")
    {
    string selected =  "dropdown is not selected"
    }
    else if(Convert.ToInt32(helmet) >= 1)
    {
    string selected = "dropdown is selected"
    return selected value;
    }
```

**Edit: **

I have  2 drop-down lists, which if selected passes the selected value to the page.

I have to check the dropdown list and then pass the values if nothing is selected then it should pass a string "nothing Selected".

If it is selected then it should do some calculation.

The problem is I have to do 5 if statements because there are 5 possibilities

1. one selected
2. one not selected
3. either way
4. both selected
5. both are not selected

Comment: You need to make your example clearer - currently you're comparing `int` with `null`, which isn't going to work to start with...

Comment: Removed the `asp.net-mvc` tag as I don't see how your question has anything to do with this technology.

Comment: Minor notes: 1). I assume your question is you need non-null `garage` and `helmet`. 2). `int` can never be `null`, do those methods return `int?`/`Nullable<int>` instead?

Comment: For starters garage and helmet would never be null because they're int's. If they're int? I'm not really seeing a way of doing it. Why do you want to remove both if statements?

Comment: sorry its 0.... not null

Comment: @Muhammad: And what are those actual "if" bodies meant to be doing? Your question is still really unclear.

Comment: I have got 2 dropdown list , which if selected passes the selected value to the page, I have to check the dropdownlist and then pass the values if nothing is selected then it should pass a string"nuthing Selected" , if it is selected then it should do some calculation , the problem is I have to do 4 if statements coz there are 4 possibilities , 1) one selected , one not selected 2) either way 3) both selected 4) both are not selected

Comment: @Muhammad: So is the logic the same for both drop-downs? Is the default value the same? Again, it would be really helpful if you could change your example to be a short but complete example which we could attempt to refactor.

Comment: sorry @Darin mvc tag was added accidentally

Comment: `pass it to view;` you can do at the end of all if statements, because you doing it in all conditions. And `dothis` doing same thing in all conditions?

Comment: updated hope it make some sense

Comment: @Reniuz .. no its returning the selected value if its selected

Comment: What do you return if both are selected?

Comment: do some calculation ... calculation is different for both the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a `switch` statement?

```
int  garage = getGarageCost(id)
int  helmet = getHelmetCost(id)

switch (garage) {

    case 0: 
        do some alternative work; 
        break;
    default: 
        everything else; 
        break;
}

switch (helmet) {

    case 0: 
        do some alternative work; 
        break;
    default: 
        everything else; 
        break;
}

pass data to view;
```

Comment: I would also do some front end validation to make sure the dropdown boxes have values.

Answer (score 1):

If both "dothis" are the same, then you can convert the int to int? and use this logic:

```
int value = getGarageCost(id) ?? getHelmetCost(id);
if (value != null)
{
    dothis()
}
else
{
    // nothing selected in both lists
}
```

.

Comment: A single `?` indicates a forced nullable type definition. The `??` operator, or null coalesce operator, takes the lefthand term if it is not null, and the right hand term as a replacement if it is.